# How can i change all the values of a multidimensional array which are greater than zero to 1 in python?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a Python `numpy` array I want to change the values of it.

Here is my array:

```
[[  0   0   0 ...,   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0 ...,   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0 ...,   0   0   0]
 ..., 
 [  0   0   0 ..., 174 152 178]
 [  0   0   0 ..., 193 157 172]
 [  0   0   0 ..., 199 173 166]]
```

How can I change all values which are greater than 0 to 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked.
I did like this:

```
a=[[0,0,0,0,0]
   [0,0,0,0,0]
   [0,0,34,34,35]
   [0,0,11,34,67]]
a[a>0]=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `a` is a `numpy` array. Then, you make use of Boolean indexing and do `a[a > 0] = 1` to change all values greater than 0 to 1. Take a look at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing for more examples.